# How to clear monitoring statistics in IBM DB2 9.7

Tags: db2

I am monitoring query information on my IBM DB2 9.7 such as how long some queries take to execute. But how do I reset this information and clear the monitors? Apparently they are reset when the whole DB instance is reset, but this forces all connections to close also on other databases in this instance (not good). Any ideas on how to reset the monitor statistics only on a particular DB? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, these monitors cannot be reset en DB2 V9.7, however you can simulate a reset by following the steps of this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1009db2monitoring1/

You create a set of objects that keep track of the values, and when you want to reset, they keep the value at that time, and then they just give the difference between the value stored and the most recent value.